# IOS bottom tab bar titles

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I can't figure out how to change the bottom bar titles on the Tab Bar.

Please see this image:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant you cannot figure it out, and you want something like in the image,

```
tabBarController.tabBarItem.title = @"Your title"
```

Answer (score 0):

In each view controller that goes into the bottom tabbar, you must specify the tab bar item:

insert this code in your init method, or viewDidLoad method.

```
UITabBarItem * tabtitle = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle: @" YOUR TITLE "
                                                        image: nil //or your image 
                                                          tag: 0];

[self setTabBarItem: tabtitle];
//[tabtitle release]; //release if not using ARC
```